# " Check whether there is an Internet connection available on flutter. "

Tags: flutter, dart, dependencies, flutter-dependencies

I have a network call to be executed. But before doing that I need to check whether the device have internet connectivity.

```
var connectivityResult = new Connectivity().checkConnectivity();// User defined class
    if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.mobile ||
        connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {*/
    this.getData();
    } else {
      neverSatisfied();
    }
```

The connectivity_plus plugin states in its docs that it only provides information if there is a network connection, but not if the network is connected to the Internet.

```
import 'dart:io';
...
try {
  final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('example.com');
  if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
    print('connected');
  }
} on SocketException catch (_) {
  print('not connected');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To check if internet is working on not then you should make an HTTP request to `'www.google.com'` and check for response code. if response `code == 200` which means everything is ok and you have working internet connection.

If you don't want to do that, then you can use `internet_connection_checker` plugin.

Comment: Here's a tutorial that can help implement it - https://medium.com/@sigmapie8/checking-network-connectivity-in-flutter-697ebcca72e